# Duplicating specific elements in lists or Numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

I work with large data sets in my research.

I need to duplicate an element in a Numpy array. The code below achieves this, but is there a function in Numpy that performs the operation in a more efficient manner?

```
"""
Example output
>>> (executing file "example.py")
Choose a number between 1 and 10:
2
Choose number of repetitions:
9
Your output array is:
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

>>>
"""
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

y = int(input('Choose the number you want to repeat (1-10):\n'))
repetitions = int(input('Choose number of repetitions:\n'))
output = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] != y:
        output.append(x[i])
    else:
        for j in range(repetitions):
            output.append(x[i])

print('Your output array is:\n', output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to find the index of the element to be repeated with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Use that index to slice the left and right sides of the array and insert the repeated array in between.

Thus, one solution would be -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(x,y)
out = np.concatenate(( x[:idx], np.repeat(y, repetitions), x[idx+1:] ))
```

Let's consider a bit more generic sample case with `x` as -

```
x = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Let the number to be repeated is `y = 5` and `repetitions = 7`.

Now, use the proposed codes -

```
In [57]: idx = np.searchsorted(x,y)

In [58]: idx
Out[58]: 2

In [59]: np.concatenate(( x[:idx], np.repeat(y, repetitions), x[idx+1:] ))
Out[59]: array([ 2,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

---

For the specific case of `x` always being `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`, we would have a more compact/elegant solution, like so -

```
np.r_[x[:y-1], [y]*repetitions, x[y:]]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much! 
I was thinking I'd need to slice the list, but I wasn't quite sure on the most elegant approach. :)

Comment: @JanCostandius For a more elegant solution for the given specific `x` posted in the question, check out the edits.

Answer (score 0):

> There is the [numpy.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) function:

```
>>> np.repeat(3, 4)
array([3, 3, 3, 3])

>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

>>> np.repeat(x, 2)
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])

>>> np.repeat(x, 3, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])

>>> np.repeat(x, [1, 2], axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```